# Ubuntu does not find connection to wireless router

Tags: wireless, internet

I've installed Ubuntu 12.10, but when I click on:

> wireless connections

my router settings couldn't not be found. Does anyone has a solution for this? I can get connection when I start up a wired connection!

Comment: Please edit your question and include result of `lspci` , `sudo lshw -c network` & `rfkill list all`. You need to execute these commands in  terminal.

Comment: Please provide more information to your question or use the search option in this site to see if there is an already existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is your SSID not broadcasting? If it is a hidden SSID you need to add you Wireless Network manually.

If this is the case you just need to click in the Wireless icon and select Connect to a hidden Wireless Network .. just enter your settings.

Checking your MAC address filter (in your router) could be a good idea as well, just a suggestion. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you don't have the necessary wireless firmware installed. This happened to me one time, and here's how I fixed it. Run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

It should download everything you need. At least it took care of my issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: You are assuming he has a broadcom driver. There is no information provided yet to determine a correct answer.